# Magento 2 add conditional mass action in sales order grid

Tags: magento2, sales-order, massaction, system-configuration

I want to add conditional mass action in sales order grid. I want to use my system configuration values to show the mass action. like we use in block layout `ifconfig="contact/contact/enabled"`

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="test">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array" >
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">test</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">test</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="test/test/test"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">test Order(s)</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't test selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
```